# Setting default context in React

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to define default contexts for components, so that if the parent component does not pass down the context to the child, the child does not break? The only thing I can think of at the moment is

```
constructor() {
    super();
    if (!this.context.role) {
        this.context.role = 'public';
    }
}
```

Would that work?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is similar to props except that a change in context doesn't actually trigger a render. Usually context takes its value from a state or a store so that's usually not a problem. Another downside is unlike props, React doesn't provide a way to set a default value for it.

You can probably make a feature request in react's repo. A workaround would be to assign a default value to it before you use it. e.g:

```
class MyComponent {
    // use this.getRole to access the role
    getRole() {
        return this.context.role || 'public';
    }
}
```

Edit: your code snippet would not work because the context value could possibly get overriden by the parent during the render pipeline; plus it's not documented what would happen when you update context object directly.